# Recursively traverse directories and retrieve last timestamp file

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, recursive

Let's suppose I have the following timestamp like directory tree:

```
root
  |__ parent1
  |      |__ 2021
  |      |     |__ 01
  |      |     |    |__ 22
  |      |     |    |    |__ 12H
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file1
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file2
  |      |     |    |    |__ 13H
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file1
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file2
  |      |     |    |__ 23
  |      |     |    |    |__ 12H
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file1
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file2
  |      |     |    |    |__ 13H
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file1
  |      |     |    |    |    |__ file2
  |__ parent2
  |      |__ etc
```

What I would like is to recursively navigate through this folder structure, so that, for each folder `parent1`, `parent2`, etc., would display the most recent timestamp found, along with a count of the files contained.
For example, something like:

```
 PARENT  |     LAST_TIMESTAMP    |  COUNT  |
--------------------------------------------
parent1  |  2021-01-23T13:00:00  |    2    |
parent2  |  2022-01-01T00:00:00  |    5    | (dummy example)
  ...             ...                ...
```

I have seen other answers but all of them take into account just the modification date of the files in all the folders, while in this case it would have to do with the name of the folders only.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Well, I've tried, as seen in other post, something like:
`
find . -type f -printf "%T@\n%p\n" | awk '
    {
        if ($0>max) {
            max=$0; 
            getline mostrecent
        } else 
            getline
    } 
    END{print mostrecent}' RS='\n'
`
But that only shows one file; the most recent one

Comment: To what other post are you referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` and a `perl` one-liner:

This use a tab to separate the timestamp and the filename, and NUL to separate each record - so will work with any filenames, including those containing newlines.

```bsh
find .. -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | 
    perl -MDate::Format -0ne '
      ($t,$f) = split /\t/,$_,2;
      (undef,$p) = split "/", $f;

      $T{$p} = $t if ($t > $T{$p});
      $count{$p}++;

      END {
        my $fmt = "%-20s | %-19s | %5s |\n";
        printf "$fmt", "PARENT", "LAST_TIMESTAMP", "COUNT";
        print "-" x 52, "\n";

        foreach (sort keys %T) {
          printf $fmt, $_, time2str("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",$T{$_}), $count{$_}
        }
      }'
```

It produces output like:

```
PARENT               | LAST_TIMESTAMP      | COUNT | 
---------------------|---------------------|-------|
foo                  | 2021-07-16T22:54:22 |     4 | 
bar                  | 2021-06-29T12:25:06 |    13 | 
baz                  | 2021-07-14T14:31:43 |     5 | 
quux                 | 2021-07-16T19:46:21 |     7 |
```

---

Alternatively, if you use perl's [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) module  you won't need to pipe `find`'s output into it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Date::Format;
use File::Find;

my %T;     # hash containing newest timestamp for each top-level dir
my %count; # count of files in each top-level dir

find(\&wanted, @ARGV);

my $fmt  = "| %-20s | %-19s | %5s |\n";
my $hfmt = "|-%-20s-|-%-19s-|-%5s-|\n";

#print "-" x 54, "\n";

printf "$fmt", "PARENT", "LAST_TIMESTAMP", "COUNT";
printf $hfmt, "-" x 20, "-" x 19, "-" x 5;

foreach (sort keys %T) {
  printf $fmt, $_, time2str("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", $T{$_}), $count{$_}
}

#print "-" x 54, "\n";

sub wanted {
  return unless -f $File::Find::name;

  # uncomment only one of the following statements:

  # get the mod time of the file itself
  my $t = (stat($File::Find::name))[9];
  # get the mod time of the directory it's in
  #my $t = (stat($File::Find::dir))[9];

  my $p = $File::Find::dir;
  $p =~ s:^\.*/::;

  $T{$p} = $t if ($t > $T{$p});
  $count{$p}++;
};
```

Save this as, e.g. `find-latest.pl`, make executable with `chmod +x find-latest.pl` and give it one or more directories as arguments when you run it:

```
$ ./find-latest.pl ../
| PARENT               | LAST_TIMESTAMP      | COUNT |
|----------------------|---------------------|-------|
| foo                  | 2021-07-16T22:54:22 |     4 |
| bar                  | 2021-06-29T12:25:06 |    13 |
| baz                  | 2021-07-14T14:31:43 |     5 |
| quux                 | 2021-07-16T19:46:21 |     7 |
```

---

This requires the perl [Date::Format](https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate)
module.  On debian, you can install it with `apt-get install libtimedate-perl`.  It should be packaged for other distros too, otherwise
install with `cpan`.

Alternatively, you can use the `strftime()` function from the POSIX module,
which is a core module, and is included with perl.

`File::Find` is also core perl module, included with perl.

Comment: awesome!! The only thing is that the timestamp is not obtained from the last modification of the file but from the folder path that leads to the file. Then, how should I modify the variable T?

Comment: you'll have to be a lot clearer, because I don't understand what you mean.  The timestamp is from the file - that's what both versions do.  The first version gets it from find -printf, the second from `$File::Find::name` (which is the complete pathname to the file).

Comment: If you mean that you want the timestamp to come from the directory that the file is in, then use `$File::Find::dir` instead of `$File::Find::name` in the second version.  The first will need to be rewritten to just process the output of `find -print0`.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to explain it better. What I mean is that the LAST_TIMESTAMP column should not refer to the last modification date of the files, but to the last timestamp according to the complete folder path for each of the "parent", as I show in the example in my initial post.

Comment: oh, when changing name to dir on the last part, script won't return files anymore

Comment: your example doesn't show where the timestamp comes from.   and your explanation still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: did you change both instances of `$File::Find::name` to `$File::Find::dir`? sorry, you only need to change the second one: `my $t = (stat($File::Find::dir))[9];`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory hierarchy structure format as shown:

```
cd root &&\
find . -type d ! -name . -path '*/*/*/*/*/*' |
sort -rt/ |
perl -sF/ -lane '$,=" | ";
  print qw(PARENT LAST_TIMESTAMP KOUNT) if $.==1;
  my $fc = -1+ split /\n/, qx(ls -l $_);
  my $parent = $F[1];
  !$seen{$parent}++ && do{
    my($dt, $tm) = ("@F[2..4]", $F[5]);
    my $timestamp = sprintf "%sT%s%s", $dt, $tm =~ s/H$//r,  (":00" x 2); 
    print $parent, $timestamp, $fc;
  };
' -- -\"=- -|column -t|
sed -e '1!b;h;s/./-/gp;x;G'
```

---

Output:-

```
----------------------------------------
PARENT  |  LAST_TIMESTAMP       |  KOUNT
----------------------------------------
pA      |  2021-03-16T23:00:00  |  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zsh`, the you can get a list of regular files in a directory `$topdir`, ordered by modification timestamp from the globbing pattern

```bsh
$topdir/**/*(.NDom)
```

It's the `(.NDom)` globbing qualifier that makes sure that the resulting list of pathnames of regular files (`.`) is ordered (`o`) by modification timestamp (`m`).  The `N` and the `D` in the qualifier acts a bit like the shell options `nullglob` and `dotglob` in `bash` shell, but for this single pattern, i.e. `N` allows the pattern to match zero names while `D` enables matching of hidden names.

The script below uses this:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %5s |\n' PARENT LAST_TIMESTAMP COUNT
printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %5s |\n' '' '' '' | tr ' ' '-'

for topdir do
        files=( $topdir/**/*(.NDom) )
        if (( ${#files} > 0 )); then
                timestamp=$( zstat -F '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' +mtime $files[1] )
        else
                timestamp=N/A
        fi

        printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %5s |\n' $topdir $timestamp ${#files}
done
```

This `zsh` script would take a set of directory paths on its command line like so:

```
$ ./script parent*/
```

... where `parent*/` would match the top-level directory names.

It prints a simple heading and then proceeds to iterate over the given directory paths.

For each path, it gets a list of pathnames of regular files (hidden names are included), ordered by the last-modified timestamp using the globbing pattern `$topdir/**/*(.NDom)`.

If this list is non-empty, the timestamp for the most recently modified file is extracted using `zstat` (a loadable shell built-in), or it is set to the string `N/A` if there were no files.

The current directory, the timestamp, and the file count is printed in a table form.

Example run:

```
$ ./script ~me/{Documents,Work,admin}/
| PARENT               | LAST_TIMESTAMP       | COUNT |
|----------------------|----------------------|-------|
| /home/me/Documents/  | 2021-06-18T13:27:39  |   816 |
| /home/me/Work/       | 2021-06-22T10:57:49  |  2582 |
| /home/me/admin/      | 2021-07-14T11:13:30  |   191 |
```

The table format used here happens to be valid markup, and the table from the example would be marked up as

| PARENT | LAST_TIMESTAMP | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /home/me/Documents/ | 2021-06-18T13:27:39 | 816 |
| /home/me/Work/ | 2021-06-22T10:57:49 | 2582 |
| /home/me/admin/ | 2021-07-14T11:13:30 | 191 |

---

In the `bash` shell, you can find the most recently modified regular file in a directory structure beneath some to-directory `$topdir` like so:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar

unset newest
for name in "$topdir"/**/*; do
        if [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -h "$name" ]; then
                if [[ "$name" -nt "$newest" ]]; then
                        newest=$name
                fi
        fi
done
```

This uses the `-nt` test in `bash` to keep track of the most recently modified file in `$newest`.  The `-f` and negated `-h` tests will be true if the current file is a regular file and not a symbolic link.

The same script as above, but written for the `bash` shell:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar

printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %5s |\n' PARENT LAST_TIMESTAMP COUNT
printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %5s |\n' '' '' '' | tr ' ' '-'

for topdir do
        unset newest
        count=0
        for name in "$topdir"/**/*; do
                # Test whether "$name" is a regular file
                # and not a symbolic link.
                if [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -h "$name" ]; then
                        count=$(( count + 1 ))
                        if [[ "$name" -nt "$newest" ]]; then
                                newest=$name
                        fi
                fi
        done

        if [ -n "$newest" ]; then
                printf -v timestamp '%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)T' "$(stat -c %Y "$newest")"
        else
                timestamp=N/A
        fi

        printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %5s |\n' "$topdir" "$timestamp" "$count"
done
```

On OpenBSD, I would use

```bsh
timestamp=$( stat -f %Sm -t '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' "$newest" )
```

in place of

```bsh
printf -v timestamp '%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)T' "$(stat -c %Y "$newest")"
```

in this script (the latter is Linux-specific).